# Cloud function: Sort firestore snapshot in memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I need to do a query with node.js to filter documents according to the age of the users and then order by the timestamp, but im getting this error in the google cloud console:

> inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: Age and Timestamp

This is my query:

```
var requestsRef = db.collection('Requests')
            .where('Age', '<=', maxAge)
            .where('Age', '>=', minAge)
            .orderBy('Timestamp');
```

is there a way to order the query by the age and then reorder the querySnapshot in the cloud function by the timestamp? and how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations):

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your
> first ordering must be on the same field

So you wont be able to do that in the query itself. You can always get the docs and order them afterwards, where it gets tricky is if you just want the 10 first...